# LESS: variable that refers to another one's value with concatenate name

Tags: less

The following (vey simplified) LESS code runs correctly, printing value of `width` property, previosly assigned to `@screen-md` variable.

```
@screen-md:700px;
@size:md;

@temp:"screen-@{size}";
@width:@@temp;

.foo
{
  width:@width;
}
```

Imagine that `@size` value could be a parameter passed to a mixin. In general, to obtain desired result, I need to pass through `@temp` variable, first assigning her a variable name based upon `@size` value, and then using [Variable name](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-names) to finally assign it to `@width` variable.

My question is: is it possible to avoid need of @temp variable, collapsing

```
@temp:"screen-@{size}";
@width:@@temp;
```

into something like `@width:@@"screen-@{size}"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to collapse it into one single line like shown below:

```css
@screen-md:700px;
@size:md;
.mixin(@size){
    width: ~"@{screen-@{size}}"; /* can either be assigned to another variable or property */
}

.output{
    .mixin(md);
}
```

**Explanation:**

- `screen-@{size}` - would evaluate to `screen-md` as the input parameter to the mixin is `md`.
- `@{screen-@{size}` - would therefore mean `@{screen-md}`. This would be evaluated as `700px`.
- `~""` - escaping is used to avoid the quotes being in printed in the output.

Comment: Thanks Harry, but I don't see `~()` statement.... I only see `~" "` and anyway, output is correct too.

Comment: @LucaDetomi Oopss sorry, I meant that only. Typo error. Nice to know it helped though :)

Comment: Thanks, anyway I don't understand why `width:@{screen-@{size}};` is not allowed. could be very easier....